# Central limit theorem does not converge to random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Recently, we investigated whether the expression in the central limit theorem converges to a random variable pointwise almost sure? The answer was negative due to $P ( \text{limsup} \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \infty)=1$. But I don't really understand this reasoning? I suspect that for almost sure convergence we would need to have that the sequence $\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is almost surely bounded, but I am not quite sure about this.

Comment: The limit of a sequence $(y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\limsup y_n=\liminf y_n<\infty$.

Comment: Why $P(\limsup\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}=\infty)=1$?

Answer (score 0):

- A convergent sequence is bounded.
- If $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\limsup_{n\to \infty}x_n= +\infty$, then this sequence is unbounded.